# How can save state into SharedPreferences in Android

Tags: android, sharedpreferences, android-sharedpreferences

I want save **isClickedState** for `imageButton`, if clicked on this `imageButton` **save this state** and change color and when not clicked show default color and save false state!

I write below codes, but when click on button not save this state and when back to other activity and go to again this activity see not save state!

**MyActivityCodes:**

```
            private ShineButton postShow_favPost;
    private String favData = "FavPrefsList";
    private Boolean favState;

    @TargetApi(Build.VERSION_CODES.LOLLIPOP)
    @Override
    protected void onCreate(Bundle savedInstanceState) {
        super.onCreate(savedInstanceState);
        setContentView(R.layout.post_show_page);

        bindActivity();

        //Give Data
        Bundle bundle = getIntent().getExtras();

        if (bundle != null) {
            title = bundle.getString("title");
            image = bundle.getString("image");
            content = bundle.getString("content");
            dateTime = bundle.getString("dateTime");
            author = bundle.getString("author");
            category = bundle.getString("category");
            categoryID = bundle.getString("categoryID");
        }

        mAppBarLayout.addOnOffsetChangedListener(this);

        //// Save Fav state
        final SharedPreferences saveFavPrefs = getSharedPreferences(favData, MODE_PRIVATE);
        final SharedPreferences.Editor editor = saveFavPrefs.edit();

        favState = saveFavPrefs.getBoolean("isChecked", false);

        postShow_favPost = (ShineButton) mToolbar.findViewById(R.id.po_image1);
        postShow_favPost.init(this);
        postShow_favPost.setOnCheckStateChangeListener(new ShineButton.OnCheckedChangeListener() {
            @Override
            public void onCheckedChanged(View view, boolean checked) {

                if (favState == true) {
                    editor.putBoolean("isChecked", true);
                    editor.commit();
                    Toast.makeText(context, "Checked True", Toast.LENGTH_SHORT).show();
                } else {
                    editor.putBoolean("isChecked", false);
                    editor.commit();
                    Toast.makeText(context, "Checked False", Toast.LENGTH_SHORT).show();
                }
            }
        });
```

How can i fix this issue?

Comment: please post your code for the color changing of the button as well.

Comment: @Saadi, please see your post answer for this colors. thaks

Comment: @Saadi, are you here saadi?

Comment: Yup. looking into it

Comment: @Saadi, please help me my friend. i really need this :(

Comment: @Saadi, are you here?

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Make the following changes to your code. In the else part make the value false again. Its important because if your isChecked value was previously true, then the else part will be able to make it false:

> I changed if(favState == true) to if(checked ==true)

```
if (checked == true) {
      editor.putBoolean("isChecked", true);
      editor.commit();
      Toast.makeText(context, "Checked True", Toast.LENGTH_SHORT).show();
 } else {
      editor.putBoolean("isChecked", false);
      editor.commit();
      Toast.makeText(context, "Checked False", Toast.LENGTH_SHORT).show();
  }
```

Comment: Thanks @Saadi, i use this library for button : https://github.com/ChadCSong/ShineButton  . and in this library when click on button change color

Comment: @Jafang could you please post the code where you put a check to change the color of the Button?

Comment: @Jafang you might probably be doing that in @onCreate() of the Activity. Please post that. That might have an issue

Comment: my dear friend i for use change color with **boolean checked** for this method  :         `postShow_favPost.setOnCheckStateChangeListener(new ShineButton.OnCheckedChangeListener() {
            @Override
            public void onCheckedChanged(View view, boolean checked) {` . in this method and above library, when `checked is true` set red for buttun and when `check is false` set gray .   please see above library link for know my mean. please . Thanks <3

Comment: and when use for codes, when click on button just show me **"checked false"**

Comment: @Jafang please see the updated answer. the if condition should be:  if (checked == true)  and not if(favState == true)

Comment: thanks, but show me issue! :( can you go to this post chant and invite i? please

Answer (score 0):

> Boolean can be check by `if(favState)` not need to do this  `if(favState == true)` boolean itself is true or false.

and save alternative state as i commented in else section.

```
               if (favState) {
                    editor.putBoolean("isChecked", checked);
                    editor.commit();
                    Toast.makeText(context, "Checked True", Toast.LENGTH_SHORT).show();
                } else {
                    //editor.putBoolean("isChecked", False);
                    //editor.commit();
                    Toast.makeText(context, "Checked False", Toast.LENGTH_SHORT).show();
                }
```

Comment: Thanks, this code is not work me! when click on button just show "Checked False" and when press back and go to again this activity, see now checked (change color) button. how can i fix this?

Comment: can you help me? i really need this. please help me :(

Answer (score 0):

If you haven't defined default value of checked as true then you need do following **as default value of boolean is false:**

**//change this**

```
editor.putBoolean("isChecked", checked);
```

**//to this**

```
editor.putBoolean("isChecked", true);
```

Let me know if this changes anything for you.